# Create an array checking previous items in another array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I'm trying to create an array of numbers, starting from a big number, which is a string, and then splited to create an array.

This array has numbers from 1 to 6.

I want to create a new array of 29 items, checking the last 3 items. For instance, if the current item to add is number 4, it will check for item 3, 2, and 1. I want it to check if any of the other 3 items are the same as the current, and if is the same, it will skip to next number.

The idea, is not to have repeated numbers in a "range" of 4 items.

I also want to do another thing, and is that if the current item is number 1, it would check the last 6 items, instead of just the last 3. Only when the item is number 1. I just haven't found a way to do it.

I hope someone could help me.

Here's the current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Randomizer {

    public static String numbers = "1632544362511653244213652164535316243164251654235231465312645164233462153465124361522316545326412354165412633214654531626513246124351423565431623162453625412564325134634562136145256142342365161423542563151426325146335241613645225431656324164351215263453642123416561345264215321536436451243156263542125631415624314536235124662145152436352164436512645312264315432651216345624315421563516423465213614352621543342516352614";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        show("\n");

        String[] nums = numbers.split("(?!^)"), finalNums = new String[29];

        for (int i = 0; i < finalNums.length; i++) {

            finalNums[i] = newnumber(nums, i);

        }

        for (String num : finalNums) {
            show(num + "-");
        }

    }

    public static String newnumber(String[] array, int start) {
        String num = "x";
        String act = array[start];
        for (int i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
            int a = start - 1, b = start - 2, c = start - 3, d = start - 4;
            if (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && d >= 0) {
                String na = array[a], nb = array[b], nc = array[c], nd = array[d];
                if (act != na && act != nb && act != nc && act != nd) {
                    num = act;
                } else {
                }
            } else {
                num = act;
            }
        }
        return num;

    }

    public static void show(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }

    public static void show(int s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }

    public static void show(float s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }

    public static void show(double s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
1-6-3-2-5-4-4-3-6-2-5-1-1-6-5-3-2-4-4-2-1-3-6-5-2-1-6-4-5
```

What I expect to get is something like:

```
1-6-3-2-5-4-6-1-2-5-3-4-6-5-1-2-5-4-6-3-2-1-2-4-5-6-3-2-1
```

Comment: How is this a duplicate?  It is an algorithm, not a string comparison?  Or unless you linked the wrong duplicate answer.

Comment: Someone else marked this as duplicate. But it isn't. I think that person didn't understand what I wanted to do.

Comment: Jahir, I have a working solution.  Are you sure about the expected value?  I think it is "1-6-3-2-5-4-6-1-3..." (so my output doesn't match your expected).  Please confirm.  Thanks

Comment: I edited it just to show an example. If you don't mind, I could check your code and tell you if is right.

Comment: How do I post code if the question is closed?  Oh ... post the 29 digit code?

Comment: No. Upload it on pastebin.com and link me to it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uJWKM8FM  (if code is correct, I'll provide code)..

Comment: Ian, the generated numbers are right, can you share the java code, please? Thanks

Comment: pastebin, or do you want to try to set up another question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AZsB329c

Comment: Thank you so much Ian. It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Hey @IanMc is there a way I can contact you? Maybe Google+ or Hangouts? ... I would like to ask you for some help if you don't mind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z1hJ3DHK.  I will help if I can.  Cheers.

Comment: The reason I closed it was that you were using `!=` to compare strings, and that is wrong in Java.  I'm no longer certain that it was the cause of any problems, since I'm not sure what you were trying to do.  However, trying to be tricky and using `==` or `!=` to compare string references is very likely to confuse everyone who reads the program.  Just don't do it.